# Rest Javascript Query Managed Metadata field

Tags: javascript, managed-metadata, rest, client-object-model

I am query a list via rest results I retrieve fine in Office 365 (sharepoint 2013).

I have two fields of which one is a managed metadata fields. I am looping through the results retrieved but when how do I get the value for the managed metadata fields.

The "Private Question" fields is not a metadata field.
The Status field is a managed metadata field which is causing an issue

The code below is the javascript looping through each item to find the value of "Status" which is showing null.

```
                results.forEach(function (result) {
                if (result.Status.Label === "66") {
                    // THIS KEEP RETURNING NOTHING
                }
                if (result.Private_x0020_Question == true) {
                    count++;
                }
            });
```

Here is the watch window from chrome as I loop through each item.

[image]

Here are the results executed as a rest query straight in the browser (so you can view in a more displayable format).

[image]

Need to know how to get the value of the Status field please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example works for me:

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listName, success, failure) {
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName +  "')/items";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}


//Usage
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents',function(results){

    results.forEach(function (result) {

        if(result.Status && result.Status.Label === "5"){
             console.log(result.Status.Label); 
        }

     });

  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

Comment: He is asking how to get the metadata field, the metadata field tags only show when select multiple is allowed, in this case this is cannot be done as it is a status field. There is no Taxonomy namespace functionality in the REST api.

Comment: Vadim I have tried the above and this works fine. So I have marked your answer as the solution required. Thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: Hugh, thank you for the constructive critique, but I assume OP was asking about obtaining taxonomy values

Answer (score 0):

The Taxonomy namespace isn't currently supported by the REST api. However you can access it via CSOM/JSOM. An example can be found here: [SharePoint 2013: Create and retrieve taxonomic metadata in apps for SharePoint](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Create-and-1ebbdd36).

You can also use a wrapper library called SPServices to get the Term for you.

Comment: Do you have a code example

Comment: The code sample is in the link, its a downloadable project from MSDN that demonstrates working with Taxonomy